# When is it OK for a moderator to delete an answer on SE Space Exploration?

Tags: discussion

We have voting and comments for addressing most issues with answer quality. Deleting is a "super power" reserved for mods. There is also "Voting to Delete" - a power that trusted users have, but that is a different topic from this question.

There might not be black-and-white rules for this, but I'll provide some links to relevant information to help make it easier to research an answer.

(By the way, an opinion-based answer is ok, just make that clear when your sharing your opinion versus restating a rule or a community guideline.)

Mods have provided [this link](https://space.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) as a source of guidance to contributors in the past. It says

> What is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – or at least a viable alternative. Your answer can say “don’t do that,” but it should also say “try this instead.” Any answer that fully addresses at least part of the question is helpful and can get the asker going in the right direction. State any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.

> Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Links to other websites should always be helpful, but avoid making it necessary to click on them as much as possible.

https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3939/when-should-answers-be-deleted says

**Answer posts that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed. This includes answers that are:**

- commentary on the question or other answers asking another, different question
- "thanks!" or "me too!"-type responses
- exact duplicates of other answers
- barely more than a link to an external site (i.e. the actual answer is not included in the post)
- not even a partial answer to the actual question

I personally speculate that additional reasons may potentially come into effect *when there are other answers*. These **may or may not be valid** reasons...

- Another answer or comment makes a compelling argument that the answer is incorrect or contains misinformation, and the author of the answer doesn't respond or make a correction within a reasonable period of time.
- The answer contains a link to something that the post's author created without a proper disclosure.
- The answer is posted *after* a better answer and adds nothing that wasn't already covered in the earlier answer(s).

This post on [Academia Meta](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/) asked a similar question and the answers reveal some of what happens behind the scenes.  https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3939/when-should-answers-be-deleted?newreg=36539f24d7fa4a56964253f9050286ae

If you have 10k+ rep, it would be great if you could use your moderator tools privilege to review some deleted answers and offer an opinion on what criteria have been used by mods to delete posts in the past.

Also feel free to share some examples of **not** valid reasons for moderators to delete and answer.

Comment: Phil - the answers on that Academia meta post are the same as here, or on most other SE sites (excluding the big 3). What do you expect from an answer here that will be different to the Academia one? There are minor variations as some sites are more accepting of subjectivity.

Comment: Well, there *are* three different answers on Academia. It would be great if each of the mods shared the specifics of their process with us. At the moment (to me at least) the process seems a bit opaque and rather inconsistent with the reasons given on the help page. I'm not suggesting that the process can't be different, just let's *be explicate* about what it is. For example, do you ever unilaterally delete, or mark "not an answer" flags as "helpful" without checking carefully against the criteria on the help page, or do you always send to the review queue, or...

Comment: What mods do is support the community in keeping quality and relevance, and upholding the code of conduct. There is no point in going down to reasons why a mod deleted this post or closed that one, as you may find 1000 posts with slightly different reasons.

Comment: Also, folks with mod privileges already see deleted questions and answers, and when they feel there is a mistake they call it out. The oversight is rather extensive.

Comment: The 3 different answers on academia all seem correct, but there are many more

Answer (score 4):

It is okay for a mod to delete any post which fails to meet guidelines, whether that is poor quality, offensiveness, spam, validating flags, or adding our instant votes to existing ones. Typically unless there is something particularly wrong with a post, we do it after flags or downvotes from the community, but sometimes if we see a bad post we'll delete anyway.

It is part of the role we were voted in to do - to be janitors ensuring standards are met.

If one of yours has been deleted and you think that was wrong (despite that decision being supported by community and at least one other mod) you can look at posts like [this one on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28867/154443).

In general, questions that are about how the entire Stack Exchange network works are often answered [here.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/154443)

The reasons you included above are all valid possible reasons for deletion, but there are many more.

Comment: I'm sorry Rory but technically this is "not even a partial answer to the actual question". But from your comment above **"What mods do is support the community in keeping quality and relevance, and upholding the code of conduct. There is no point in going down to reasons why a mod deleted this post or closed that one, as you may find 1000 posts with slightly different reasons."** suggest that you process 1000's of posts and the reasons vary. What I'm inferring from this is that you *are* unilaterally deleting answers and it's a personal judgment call in each case.

Comment: Again, you have misunderstood, whether deliberately or accidentally. The reason is the same every time - they do not meet site requirements. But you realise mods can unilaterally decide to delete posts if we feel they deserve it. It is part of our role. I strongly suggest you read the Meta entries re mods as I feel your problem is a misunderstanding of what our role is, or you're upset at some of your posts not meeting standards, as set by the community and SE.

Comment: That said, it is reasonably rare that unilateral deletion is required - this is almost always flagging or voting by the community first. As in the case of the posts of yours that have been deleted.

Comment: Again - learn what makes a good post, and the community will upvote. The action is on you to improve here if your posts are being downvoted or flagged. Nothing to do with mods - everything to do with this community.

Comment: Thanks Rory, This is more helpful. I think you can remove the "If you are upset" paragraph as that's not relevant to the question. I would like this question to capture a kind of a rubric that people can try to understand. What is relevant is the last statement "There are many more" - especially to the degree that these are not formally defined anywhere. I would still like to see more answers and perspectives from other people! Especially other mods, people who use the "delete flag" for some of the "many more" reasons, and people who, as a rule, rarely use the delete flag.